# Disable DNS proxy in Internet Connection Sharing

Tags: windows-7, bind, ics

I have BIND installed and ICS enabled.

When computer starts, ICS binds 53 port before BIND.

I tried to set ICS dependency from BIND, but looks like named need some time before port binding, and ICS still can bind port before named.

How can I disable DNS proxy in ICS or delay it start enought, that named can bind 53 port?

Comment: Is this question on-topic here? Should it be asked on serverfault.com?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft says it can't be done. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/250603

I hope someone finds a way to disable ICS's DNS - or at least let me configure it so it can return this computer's address for one particular host name.